# I have a question about C ++ boost :: asio and std :: async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, asio

I know that both are designed asynchronously.

What I'm curious about is the function callback when creating a thread using the above two.

Is it possible for a single thread to write and read asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact I have many examples of that on this site.

I wrote one yesterday that starts out with true single-threading:

- [How to pass a boost asio tcp socket to a thread for sending heartbeat to client or server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082814/how-to-pass-a-boost-asio-tcp-socket-to-a-thread-for-sending-heartbeat-to-client/62090362#62090362)

Note that you can easily also do multi-client servers on a single thread:

- [Boost.Asio: Is it a good thing to use a `io_service` per connection/socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486010/boost-asio-is-it-a-good-thing-to-use-a-io-service-per-connection-socket/31486112#31486112)
- With a twist (because it wants to synchronize writing to all clients) [Thread-safety when accessing data from N-theads in context of an async TCP-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304403/thread-safety-when-accessing-data-from-n-theads-in-context-of-an-async-tcp-serve/50307112#50307112)

There must be many more, but these are the first hits I see.